# Adding a new row to html table on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list with names, each name has a sublist with subitems.
I need to pass those subitems to the table when I click on the name.
[Here](http://codepen.io/Ghaleon/pen/zGQMpw) is an example, try to expand the first name.
But if I click on it again, it will keep adding that value to different  cells of the table. How may I add this only once ? Or always at the same place?

Also, I have some attributes of the disciplines:

`data-time` = The time the discipline start;
`data-id` = The ID of that discipline (all brought from database);

My Code:

```
/*JQuery*/
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".prof-list h3").click(function(event){
        var obj = event.target; 
        var disciplina_id = $(this).next().find('li').data('id');
        var disciplina_hora = $(this).next().find('li').data('time');
        if(disciplina_hora == "14:30:00"){
            var myRow = document.getElementById("prof-table").rows[3];
            myRow.insertCell(1).innerHTML = $(this).next().find('li').text();
        }
        else if(disciplina_hora == "08:30:00"){
            var myRow = document.getElementById("prof-table").rows[1];
            myRow.insertCell(1).innerHTML = $(this).next().find('li').text();   
        }

        if(obj.nodeName == "H3")
            $(this).next().slideToggle();//Aplica efeito slide
        //$("#list_prof").html("clicked: " + event.target.nodeName ); //Teste
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.cells[]` to update cell content

```
if(disciplina_hora == "14:30:00"){
    var myRow = document.getElementById("prof-table").rows[3];

    // insert if `myRow` only has 1 cell
    if(myRow.cells.length <= 1)
      myRow.insertCell(1);

    // use `cells[1]` to update the 2nd cell content 
    myRow.cells[1].innerHTML = $(this).next().find('li').text();
}
```

**Edit Update**

```
if(myRow.cells.length <= 1){
    $(this).next().find('li').each(function(idx, elm) {
      myRow.insertCell(idx + 1);    
      myRow.cells[idx + 1].innerHTML = $(elm).text();
    });
} else {
    while(myRow.cells.length > 1)
        myRow.deleteCell(1);
}
```

Comment: hey man, try again in codepen please. If you try to move items of a teacher that has more than one discipline, all the discipline goes to the same place of the `<td>`. Is there a way to make something like a foreach ?

Comment: Perfect ! You Rock !!  If it's not too much, could you explain to me how `idx` and `elm` has value how they are something. I mean, you just write them as parameter but how do they have some value, some meaning ... ?

Comment: You're the best, man. Sorry for ask this kind of thing but, I'll need to make some change on this later,  make something more complex (is there a way to tag you in the question) ?